# How to remove the blue border around ImageMap control in the Internet Explorer?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an image with hotspots, therefore I am using the ImageMap control. The problem now is with the image used with this control. It will be shown with blue border around it. I have this problem before with  and I fixed it with the following CSS code:

```
 a img
{
    border:none;
    }
```

Now, how to apply this to the ImageMap control?

I already tried to fix it using:

```
<div style="border:none;"> </div>
```

but it did not work and I don't know why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
<div style="border:none;"> </div>
```

You tell the renderer that the div should not have a border, not the image.

Similarly when you use this CSS code:

```
a img
{
border:none;
}
```

You are telling the browser that an image within an anchor tag should have no borders.
Try the following code:

```
img { border: none; }
```

This will remove borders from all images on the page. You might want to increase the specificity of that statement if you want to have some images with borders.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanation. Finally, I got it and understood my mistakes. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The border is around the `img` - you need to set the `img` border to `none`. There is no `a` element anywhere as the hotspots are controlled by the image map:

```
img
{
    border:none;
}
```